# Increase VPN Connection Attempt Timeout to Greater Than 60 Seconds

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager, vpn, nmcli

I have OpenVPN connection that - for some reason - takes too long to connect.

However, when I use the `nmcli connection up MyOpenVPN_TCP` command it keeps trying to connect **for only 60 seconds**, and I need to increase that duration.

I get the following error message:

> Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown reason
>
> Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION={*SOME_SERIAL*} + NM_DEVICE={*MY_WLAN_INTERFACE*}' to get more details.

And when I run that **journalctrl** command, I just get the following log:

> starting openvpn
>
> dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)

And when I **monitor the DBus** NetworkManager's VPN interface, I get the following log:

> signal time=1677534191.881782 sender=:1.328 -> destination=(null destination) serial=527 path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Connection; member=VpnStateChanged
> uint32 2    uint32 1
>
> signal time=1677534191.883698 sender=:1.328 -> destination=(null destination) serial=544 path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Connection; member=VpnStateChanged
> uint32 3    uint32 1
>
> signal time=1677534252.361651 sender=:1.328 -> destination=(null destination) serial=582 path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Connection; member=VpnStateChanged
> uint32 6    uint32 0

Am I missing something? Any idea on how to increase that timeout?

---

What I've tried so far with no luck:

1. in my VPN connection configuration file: **/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyOpenVPN_TCP.nmconnection**: adding `timeout=90` under section `[vpn]` (*it works though when I set it to something less than 60; I get timeout error message instead of the unknown reason*)
2. in the NetworkManager global config file: **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

   - adding `vpn.timeout=90` under section `[connection]` (*same behavior like previous one*)
3. in the OpenVPN config file: **MyOpenVPN_TCP.ovpn**: adding `hand-window 90', then re-import the config file, but I see nothing new added to the MyOpenVPN_TCP.nmconnection file (I was expecting timeout=90 under [vpn]!
4. replace binary `/usr/sbin/openvpn` with shell script that passes `--hand-window 90`, so that whenever NetworkManager starts openvpn, it's started with `hand-window=90`.

However, when I explicitly start openvpn with the following command, the handshake waits 90 seconds instead of 60:

```
sudo openvpn --hand-window 90 --config MyOpenVPN_TCP.ovpn
```

The only workaround I could do so far is to keep retrying to connect until it succeeds, using some shell script loop.

---

My configs are:

**1. /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

> [main]
>
> plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
>
> [ifupdown]
>
> managed=false
>
> [device]
>
> wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
>
> [connection]
>
> #**vpn.timeout=90**

**2. /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyOpenVPN_TCP.nmconnection**

> [connection]
>
> id=MyOpenVPN_TCP
>
> uuid=7f9b3356-b210-4c0e-8123-bd116c9c280f
>
> type=vpn
>
> timestamp=1676641002
>
> [vpn]
>
> auth=SHA256
>
> ca=MyOpenVPN_TCP.p12
>
> cert=MyOpenVPN_TCP.p12
>
> cert-pass-flags=0
>
> cipher=AES-256-GCM
>
> connection-type=password-tls
>
> dev=tun
>
> key=MyOpenVPN_TCP.key
>
> password-flags=1
>
> push-peer-info=yes
>
> remote={*SERVER_IP*}:443:tcp-client
>
> remote-cert-tls=server
>
> ta=MyOpenVPN_TCP.key
>
> ta-dir=1
>
> username={*MY_VPN_USERNAME*}
>
> verify-x509-name=name:freeradius-temp-server
>
> service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
>
> #**timeout=90**
>
> [vpn-secrets]
>
> cert-pass={*CERT_PWD*}
>
> [ipv4]
>
> method=auto
>
> [ipv6]
>
> addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
>
> method=auto
>
> [proxy]

---

**System details:**

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-Bit
- NetworkManager 1.36.6
- OpenVPN 2.5.5

---

**OpenVPN Client Log**

When I run the following command:

```
sudo openvpn --hand-window 93 --config MyOpenVPN_TCP.ovpn
```

or add `hand-window 93` to the OpenVPN config file: MyOpenVPN_TCP.ovpn, then run the following command:

```
sudo openvpn --config MyOpenVPN_TCP.ovpn
```

It works, and I get the following log:

> 2023-02-23 14:01:53 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]{*SERVER_IP*}:443
>
> 2023-02-23 14:01:53 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]{*SERVER_IP*}:443 [nonblock]
>
> 2023-02-23 14:01:53 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]{*SERVER_IP*}:443
>
> 2023-02-23 14:01:53 TCP_CLIENT link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:0
>
> 2023-02-23 14:01:53 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]{*SERVER_IP*}:443
>
> 2023-02-23 14:03:26 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur
> within 93 seconds (check your network connectivity)
>
> 2023-02-23 14:03:26 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed 2023-02-23 14:03:26 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
>
> 2023-02-23 14:03:26 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
>
> 2023-02-23 14:03:31 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]{*SERVER_IP*}:443

Answer (score 0):

I think the first option you tried is overridden by the config file of nm. In the 2nd, i think you are modifying the default config from the os. try to create your own under /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d.. and when you set it less or more than default of 60, see of it changes along